# JW player unlisted youtube videos

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, jwplayer

I have an unlisted youtube video i'm adding to JWplayer, however it keeps returning an error:

GET file://www.youtube.com/iframe_api net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

is this because the video is set to unlisted or what?

my code:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="video"></div><!--video-->

</div><!--wrapper-->

<script>
jwplayer("video").setup({
    file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pvig3OZe2nc",
    width: 640,
    height: 360
});
```

Comment: If it's not public it will not show. I don't know the ins and outs of JW Player or YouTube's API but essentially, if this *did* work, anyone could view an unlisted video if they only had the url by using the code you have there.  You would either need some OAuth credentials or, more likely, it will need to be publicly listed.

Comment: Correct. It has to be a public, shareable, embeddable video.

Comment: Indeed, needs to be public.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I found my own answer to my problem though.

I was testing locally, and the YouTube API will not load with JWPlayer locally. Added it to a web server and loaded flawlessly.

Thanks anyways.